# What is the definite way to debug backend and frontend at the same time in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

It seems there are 1 million launch configurations out there, and the more you try the more confused you get.

As of 2/6/22 what is the way to launch debugger so it will work for both Nodejs `(npm start debug = nodemon --inspect index.js)` AND also work for bundled + sourcemap + minified JS on frontend

Comment: Generally speaking, _you don't_. Instead you launch two separate instances: one for the front-end and one for the backend, and have each debugging each separately.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your project, however you do not really much custom configurations with VS Code since mostly is done automatically, the least way of debugging your nodejs project, is by simply attaching your debugger to nodejs running process, here is an example of one of my `launch.json` configurations:

```
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "attach",
      "name": "Attach to process",
      "sourceMaps": true,
      "processId": "${command:PickProcess}",
      "restart": true,
      "protocol": "inspector"
    },
```

If you want to debug nodejs from it's starting point since attaching happens after it already started (this is if you are using `nodemon` - nodemon is a tool we use to monitor the code changes and rebuild-rerun for us everytime we make a change):

```
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Debug watch api",
      "outFiles": [
        "${workspaceFolder}/dist/..." // in my case, i have typescript and my nodejs build goes into that folder
      ],
      "runtimeArgs": ["${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/nodemon/bin/nodemon"],
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "args": ["--config", "nodemon-debug.json"],
      "sourceMaps": true,
      "autoAttachChildProcesses": true,
      "protocol": "inspector",
      "serverReadyAction": {
        "action": "openExternally",
        "uriFormat": "http://localhost:3000",
        "pattern": "<what-string-do-you-want-vscode-to-see-to-open-a-browser-for-you-automatically>"
      },
      "env": {
        "TS_NODE_PROJECT": "tsconfig.build.json",
      }
    },
```

example `nodemon-debug.json`:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/nodemon",
  "watch": ["src"],
  "ext": "ts",
  "ignore": ["src/**/*.spec.js"], // what files to ignore from watching
  "exec": "node --trace-uncaught --nolazy {{pwd}}/src/main.js"
}
```

Generally, all you need is to configure `.vscode/launch.json` file, vscode automatically debugs for you. See https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging for more details.

You can debug as many processes as you want at the same time via `Start additional session` (if your api and ui are on 2 different processes).

[image: debug additional process]